# Linking error iLBC codec library from webRTC to iOS app

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, webrtc, static-libraries

I've been trying to include libilbc.a library from the webRTC project into my iOS app. I'm linking it to static library (c++, Xcode project) and then linking this library to my iOS app. It's all in one workspace.

I'm stuck on the next linking error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64: 
>    "_WebRtcIlbcfix_EncoderInit", referenced from:

If I check the library architecture I get the right info:

> $ lipo -info libilc.a 
>   $ Non-fat file: libilbc.a is architecture: arm64

Also if I check the content of the library, it includes the object:

> $ nm libilbc.a | grep "_WebRtcIlbcfix_EncoderInit" 
>     $ U _WebRtcIlbcfix_EncoderInit

I have included header files into the Xcode project and linked with -lilbc flag.

Remark: 
I have successfully build the same project for simulator with different library that I got on Github and it worked (meaning, there is nothing wrong with the linking or including header files). The problem is that mentioned library isn't compiled for arm64 architecture.

I would really appreciate if someone knows where could I get compiled ilbc library (for ios arm64) or how to integrate the library from the webRTC project.

Comment: Maybe the `U` in: `U _WebRtcIlbcfix_EncoderInit` means undefined symbol? As in the library knows it needs that symbol but expects another library to supply it.

Comment: Checking the nm, manual: "U The symbol is undefined."

Comment: You are right :) I built my own library and it worked...